# Seriously What's wrong in my code

Tags: c

I am trying to solve one problem from spoj http://www.spoj.com/problems/ARITH2/

But every time i am getting 'WA' Wrong Answer.I've tried every possible Test Case and it's giving me expected results.I've written the code mentioned below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int t,s=0;char operator;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        signed long long int s=0,c=0;
        scanf("%lld",&s);
        while(1)
        {
            operator=0;
            operator=getc(stdin);
            if(operator=='=')
                break;
            scanf("%lld",&c);
            switch(operator)
            {
                case '+' : s=s+c;
                       break;
                case '-' : s=s-c;
                       break;
                case '*' : s=s*c;
                       break;
                case '/' : s=s/c;
                       break;
            }
        }
        printf("%lld\n",s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is on line 53.  You gave have inverted the metric converter.  :-)

Comment: @KetanSethi Please use proper indentation, this code is unreadable for everyone, including you and makes debugging and maintaining it much harder.

Comment: Try to learn debugging such stuff yourself. You might like to read here on how do do this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Serious question, what are your `scanf` calls supposed to achieve? Did you check the return value? is `%10000` a valid format? ... Indentation is a bit better now, but still far from readable.

Comment: On the odd chance this is something weird that I've never seen before, what the heck is `%10000` in `scanf("%llu%10000",&s);`? I don't see anything like it mentioned as a valid format token and can't make a sample compile without warning.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the requirement, you should not use `scanf` instead, using `sscanf` cos the input is whole expression such `50 * 40 * 250 + 791 =`. You can create a simple parser as below code to walkthrough whole expression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char ch = 0;
    int state = 0;
    char buff[128];
    char ops = 0;
    unsigned int result = 0;
    int i = 0, idx = 0;

    char expr[1024];
    int cnt = 0;

    if (scanf("%[^=]=%n", expr, &cnt) <= 0)
        return 0;

    while(idx < cnt) {
        ch = expr[idx++];

        printf("state %d ch %c\n", state, ch);
        switch(state) {
            case 0:
                if ((ch <= '9') && (ch >= '0')) {
                    state++;
                    buff[i++] = ch;
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                if ((ch <= '9') && (ch >= '0')) {
                    buff[i++] = ch;
                } else {
                    buff[i] = '\0';
                    if (i > 0) {
                        unsigned int num = atoi(buff);

                        switch (ops) {
                            case '-':
                                result -= num;
                                break;

                            case '+':
                                result += num;
                                break;

                            case '*':
                                result *= num;
                                break;

                            case '/':
                                result /= num;
                                break;

                            default:
                                result = num;
                                break;
                        }

                        printf("> found fact %d, result %u\n", num, result);
                    }

                    i = 0;

                    if ((ch == '-') || (ch == '+') || (ch == '*') || (ch == '/')) {
                        state = 0;
                        ops = ch;
                        printf("> found ops %c\n", ch);
                    } else if ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t')) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (ch == '=') {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // expression end
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("> result '%u' ", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick glance, it doesn't look like you are respecting the spacing outlined in the spec. For example, 1 + 1 * 2 = is going to read the wrong character for operator. 1+1*2= looks like it'll work, but that's not what was asked for.

Also, you're reading in unsigned integers and will instantly fail any test cases with signed numbers.

Comment: I've updated my code to signed integers but still don't know how to  respecting the spacing outlined in the spec.Can you please help.I am trying scanf("%d%1",&input);